# MPI MULTIPLE SPAWN: number of processes in child

Tags: mpi, spawn

I need to spawn multiple processes from only one original process.

The parent looks like this, it spawns two processes:

```
  int ncommands = 2;
  
  //definition of arrays in arguments, and here the one that I am interested in:
   
  for(int ic = 0; ic < ncommands; ic++) nprocs[ic] = 1;

  MPI_Comm_spawn_multiple(2, commands,MPI_ARGVS_NULL,nprocs, 
  infos,0,MPI_COMM_SELF,&child,errcodes);
```

This calls the executable correctly, but I don't understand the number of processors in the child code.

I expect to set with the array nprocs a maximum of one processor per command. This is very
important to my code because the child executable does not work with more than one process (basically there is a system solver that does not support parallelization). However, when I print in the child the size obtained from MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpisize), it returns 2. And indeed, I can't do what I need in the child because it is trying to parallelize the problem between two processes.

How to make only one process to be used in the child ? Why the size I get is 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `spawn_multiple` call does what the documentation says: "Spawns multiple binaries [...], establishing communication with them and placing them in the same MPI_COMM_WORLD."

If you want to spawn multiple programs, but making each a separate `COMM_WORLD`, use a sequence of calls to `MPI_Comm_spawn`.